# Grails domain constructor with JSON parameter did not work

Tags: json, grails, groovy

I have such controller in my grails project:

```
def submit() {
    def json = request.JSON
    Share share = new Share(json)
    share.save(flush: true,  failOnError: true)
}
```

Class Share looks like this:

```
class Share {

    String timestamp
    String deviceName
    String originMessage

Share(JSONObject originalMessage) {
    println "Run JSON constructor"
    println "$originalMessage"

    originMessage = originalMessage.toString()
    timestamp = originalMessage.timestamp
    deviceName = originalMessage.device
}
```

It recives JSON request and try to persist in data base.

I get such error in my console on failOnError:

- Field error in object 'com.entity.Share' on field 'deviceName': rejected value [null];
- Field error in object 'com.entity.Share' on field 'originMessage': rejected value [null]; codes

A lot of dancing around find one possible way: in controller convert JSON to string and pass it in constructor where parameter would be type String and then parse it back in JSON using JSON converter. But why I can not pass JSON Object as parameter correctly. What happens?

Comment: Remove your constructor and try again. Grails already have this kind of constructor for domain classes.

Comment: Yes, I know it, but I dislike mapping style of constructor. Nevertheless why I see such strange behavier?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see much point in declaring this constructor because domain classes already have an implicit constructor that takes a `Map` argument. You could call this constructor with the `JSONObject` because this class implements `Map`, e.g.

```
class Share {

    String timestamp
    String deviceName
    String originMessage
}

def json = request.JSON
Share share = new Share(json)
```

The reason for these errors

```
Field error in object 'com.entity.Share' on field 'deviceName': rejected value [null];
Field error in object 'com.entity.Share' on field 'originMessage': rejected value [null]; codes
```

is that your `JSONObject` instance does not have non-null properties named `deviceName` or `originMessage`.

Either you need to figure out why these properties are missing, or allow these properties to be null by adding the following constraints to the domain class

```
class Share {

    String timestamp
    String deviceName
    String originMessage

    static constraints = {
        deviceName nullable: true
        originMessage nullable: true 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know about default constructors in groovy. Map style with JSON usefull, but as you could see originalMessage is not just field, but original JSON request. Of course I could still use Map costructor just enumerating all fields with values, but I also dislike Map style, that's why I made my own constructor. About message of error, yes I see what it says to me and my question about exact the same Why this properties are missing in this case and work perfect in case of string?